# Deploy project Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, vendor

I have a project in laravel, that when I run it on my computer everything works fine. The problem is when I loaded it in git and cloned it in a vps.

ORACLE CLOUD
[image]

VULTR CLOUD
[image]

It's the same problem

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

I thought it was the service, but I see that it is the project. Maybe it is recompiling or something like that?

Comment: I'm afraid you don't offer enough information in order to be able to post an informed response. The code I see in the image screenshot, deliberately logs that issue.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Comment: how did you run it on your computer? using artisan serve? if so, did you run artisan serve on your hosting too? the error happens probably because there is no http server to handle the request. you can also check out the deployment page in the official laravel documentations